# HTML Javascript font size change

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function test(){
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
      document.write("name="+name+"");
      document.write("&snumber="+snumber+"<br />");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
     Name :
   <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
     Student number:
   <input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the font size of 6th and 7th lines' result to h2 size
I can change in body section by putting

```
 <h2></h2>
```

however, it's not working in a script section. If I input data in name and snumber section, It connects to a new page that shows inputs like "name=David&snum=21467564" I want this font size to be h2 size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `h2` tag

Single line output:

```js
function test(){
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
    
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"");
 document.write("&snumber="+snumber+"</h2> <br/>");
 }
```

```html
<h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
     Name :
   <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
     Student number:
   <input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
```

For multiline output: Just close `<h2>` tag and start new heading tag like:

```
document.write("<h2>name="+name+"</h2>");
document.write("<h2>snumber="+snumber+"</h2><br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    name= "<span style='font-size:32px;'>"+name+"</span>";
    snumber= "<span style='font-size:32px;'>"+snumber+"</span>";
    var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
    document.write("name="+name+"");
    document.write("&snumber="+snumber+"<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function test(){
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"</h2>");
 document.write("<h2>&snumber="+snumber+"</h2><br />");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! just add h2 element.

```js
function test(){
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"</h2>");
 document.write("<h2>&snumber="+snumber+"</h2>");
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
Name :
<input type="text" id="name"><br/>
Student number:
<input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
function test(){
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"</h2>");
 document.write("<h2>snumber="+snumber+"</h2><br />");
}
```

```html
<h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
Name :
<input type="text" id="name"><br/>
Student number:
<input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(){
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var snumber = document.getElementById('snumber').value;
    
 document.write("<h2>name="+name+"</h2>");
 document.write("<h2>&snumber="+snumber+"</h2> <br/>");
 }
```

```html
<h2>Example of sending data using POST</h2>
     Name :
   <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
     Student number:
   <input type="text" id="snumber"><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="test();">
```